# Ghost script remove duplicate embedded subset fonts

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdfa

I am converting a PDF file to PDF/A file with PDF/A-2b specification with help of ghost script 9.52.

```
gswin64 -dPDFA=2 -dBATCH  -dNOPAUSE -dFastWebView -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=pdf_output_1.pdf PDFA_def2.ps input.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress pdfmarks.txt
```

After converting , when I check the pdf/a file with Adobe Preflight, I am getting a warning as follows.

"a font with same name is embedded multiple times. This can lead to wrong if the PDF viewer cannot differentiate these fonts"

When I see the `Fonts` option from the properties, I am able to see , same CIDFonts are added multiple times as follows.

[image: pdfa font list]

I am able to fix this issue via preflight option with clicking `Fix` in Adobe Pro. With that fix, font names are suffixed with auto incrementer values and getting unique in name.

But my requirement is for doing this via GS itself via script.

Any help appreciated !!

Comment: Firstly; there's no reason why you can't have a font with the same name embedded multiple times, especially on different pages or with a different PDF name. The warning is probably due to the fact that some PDF consumers assume font names are unique and is just that, a warning. Other than that, there isn't anything anyone can say without the original PDF file to look at. Note that the list of fonts from Acrobat does not list the actual font names (it misses off the subset prefix) and so is not helpful. Also I wouldn't trust the Acrobat pre-flight tool. If you want to check it use VeraPDF.

Comment: @KenS i had tried with veraPDF already to check the conformance , and it is successful. Our vendor uses acrobat Pre-flight. When they do PDF analysis on preflight , they get this warning report. They want us to remove this warning as well.

Comment: I also just realised you are using an old version of Ghostscript (9.52) you should try something less than 3.5 years old. The current version is 10.01.2 and 10.02.0 will be released shortly.

Comment: The word 'vendor' makes this sound like commercial use of Ghostscript to me, do you have a commercial license ? Otherwise my earlier comments stand, try using more up to date software and the fact that Acrobat's miserable pre-flight tool gives an error doesn't mean there is one. If your 'vendor' doesn't like that then they need educating IMO. Also there is likely nothing you can do without changing the pdfwrite device source code (and possibly not even then) which I doubt you want to do, so you need to open a bug report and attach the original file.

Comment: We use GPL licenced version only which is available in our central maven repo. Anyway I will try with latest version as well. Thanks @KenS

Comment: It's AGPL, not GPL, so SaaS use is covered by the licence as well. As long as you are confident that your usage conforms to the AGPL that's fine, I felt I should warn you though.

Comment: Thanks @KenS , we use AGPL version only.

Comment: I'm not saying you are not using the AGPL version, but you should make certain your usage is compliant with the AGPL. If you are distributing Ghostscript to someone else, then you are sailing close to the wind, especially if you are selling it as part of a product or service. If you are certain you are compliant that's absolutely fine, I'm not saying you are not compliant, just suggesting that you check.